# keep data in memory persistently

Tags: python, python-3.x, persistent-storage

I want to write a `Python` script which loads 2 GB of data from the hard disk into memory and then whenever requested by other program, it must get an input and do some calculations on this data based on the input. the important thing for me is to keep this 2 GB data in memory persistently to speed up the calculations and more importantly avoid huge I/O load.

how should I keep the data in memory forever? or more generally, how should I solve such problem in Python?

Comment: Are you sure inter-process communication is the best way to improve performance? Why not load it in memory in the same process that wants to use the data?

Comment: @kaya3 it is not an inter-process communication. the same script which runs the calculations is supposed to keep the data as well.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "whenever requested by other program"?

Comment: another program is supposed to send a request to my python program, and then it must do the calculations based on the data is has already loaded and return the result. so loading and calculating is done by one python program.

Comment: OK - and I presume the query and response themselves take relatively little memory compared to the data that is required to perform the calculation?

Comment: @kaya3 exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what kind of data you have, you can keep the data in a Python list, set, hashmap or any other data structure. If this is just meant to be a cache, you can use a server like Redis or memcached too.

There is nothing special about loading data to memory "forever" or doing it every time you need it. You can just load into Python variables and keep them around.

Comment: He is talking about 2GB of data!!! is loading it into a variable the best option?

Comment: Of course, why would there be a problem with keeping 2GB of data in a Python data structure? As long as you have more than 2GB of free memory, everything will work smoothly.

Comment: @AvenDesta It's fairly typical for computers to have 16-32 GB nowaday. So I'd argue that as long OP is aware of the load, it's not a bad option at all.

Comment: I load it into a variable as a list for example, then the script runs some calculations and ends (since there is no new request at that time). so what happens to the variable now? the script has ended and so the variable gets freed, doesn't it?

Comment: @Soheil The Python garbage collector will free the memory if there is no more reference to the variable/list. Just make sure to have no reference to the variable/list once the data is no longer needed. In particular, if you load the data in a global variable, it will stay in memory as long as the module is referenced or until you do a del on the variable.

Comment: @Soheil you will need to keep the script running. Since you didn't provide too many details in the original post about what you are doing, it's not easy to give recommendations.

Comment: @Soheil You will want to turn your script into a service probably. Try using a module such as `bottle` and expose an HTTP API.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon this is my question actually! how to avoid garbage collection of this variable! I want to keep it in memory for the next requests!

Comment: Also you should be aware that files you used recently will be kept in the filesystem cache of your system, and future reads will be much faster without even hitting the disk.

Comment: @Soheil Just keep a reference to the variable and the gc will not collect it. If there exist a semantic way to access the data in your program, then it is still in memory.

Comment: @GokberkYaltirakli more details: I want to keep the feature vectors of 100,000 images (~ 2 GB) in memory so that I can calculate the similarity (via cosine similarity) of each new image (given in input) to all those 100,000 images as quickly as possible.

Comment: And why is it not acceptable to keep this script running as a service instead of exit'ing after running it once?

Comment: @GokberkYaltirakli TBH I'm a java expert and new to Python. are Python services exactly what satisfies my needs in this case?

Comment: @Soheil It depends on the load you expect to put on that script. I personally would go for Gokberk Yaltirakli suggestion to use Redis. This would be a perfectly acceptable, clean and maintainable Python solution.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon so using Redis is preferred to using the script a service in my case?

Comment: If Redis can do the filtering / searching you need, you can use it. Otherwise you will need to make a service. How are you running this script "for each new input image". Isn't there something running all the time to get new images?

Comment: @GokberkYaltirakli there is another java program running all the time to get the images BUT sometimes I have to stop it to make some changes and run it again. so it is not actually running non-stop!

Comment: That's good. So instead of running the script every time, you can keep the script running and answer HTTP requests for example. You can also put the images into a directory with the Java program and read the response from another directory, if you want to use files instead of using a server.

Comment: @GokberkYaltirakli so by using a module like Bottle, the script will be kept running forever? I didn't get what you mean by `if you want to use files instead of using a server`!

Comment: If you use a module like Bottle or Flask, the script will run forever. If you want to call a function on the service using Java, you would use a library like OkHttp or ApacheHttpClient.

Comment: @GokberkYaltirakli I have to actually make POST/GET requests to communicate with my python service. right? so it seems to be the best/easiest solution in my case!

Comment: Yes, you would need to make a POST or GET request to your Python service. Most likely the actual computation you do on the image will take longer than doing a request to a locally-running service, so the performance impact should be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have 2GB of free and available RAM and then use the mmap module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) to map the entire array into active memory.